# How to test web service

Tags: java, integration-tests, maven, jenkins

I want to test my web service/web method not by using SOAP but with Junit or other framework. The first solution that I have founded is to create stub of my project and use a client to call this method; but what I want to do, is not to use a client, but directly call my webmethod inside my project; I am using maven and the project is on Jenkins, so with Jenkins I want to test my test method.
I have try this to call a webmethod:

```
private Report reportBean = new Report();
@Mock
HttpSession mockedSession = mock(HttpSession.class);
@Before
public void injectMockEntityManager(){
    EntityManager entityManager = mock(EntityManager.class);
    reportBean.emReport = entityManager;
    Functions fnct= mock(Functions.class);
    reportBean.fnct=fnct;
}

@Test
public void testReport() throws WSException {
    reportBean.getReport("myReport", new Date(), new Date());
TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
}
```

The Report and Functions class is @Stateless, and in Report I use @EJB to call the functions class, what I have see is every time I call a method that is in a EJB like functions.getElement return null, so there is an alternative to call the web method without use a client like I have explained at the beginning or not ? thanks

Comment: Have you written unit tests?

Comment: no, integration test

Comment: Then how can you be sure the web methods even work unless they're a very thin layer?

Comment: Sorry @Robbie Dee I don't understand your question,what do you mean with " unless they're a very thin layer?"

Comment: You should really be writing and executing unit tests before integration testing. The exception might be where you have a very thin layer that itself calls another layer. By "thin", I mean that all that web method does is call a method in another layer.

Comment: I can't try unit test before integration test, and don't solve my problem, how can I test crud method without integration test? I have try to connect to the database with dbunit and It work's but I am thinking if there is another way to test this web method withouth creating a stub of this method etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test your "Report" by making it webservice independant through a java  interface like this:

```
public interface ReportApi {
    void getReport(String templateName, Date orderDate, Date printDate);
}

// webservice independant implementation of ReportApi
public ReportImpl implements ReportApi {
    public void getReport(String templateName, Date orderDate, Date printDate) {
        // ... generate report
    }
}   

// thin WebService wrapper around some ReportApi implementation run on the webserver
public ReportWebService extends SomeWebServiceBaseClass implements ReportApi {
    private ReportApi reportImplementation;
    public ReportWebService (String serviceUrl, ReportApi reportImplementation) {
        ...
        this.reportImplementation = reportImplementation;
    }
    public void getReport(String templateName, Date orderDate, Date printDate)  {
        this.reportImplementation.getReport(templateName, orderDate, printDate);
    }
}

// thin wrapper for WebService-client used by the client to call the WebService functionality
public ReportWebServiceWrapper extends SomeWebServiceBaseClass implements ReportApi {
    ...
}
```

All your report consumer needs to know is the interface ReportApi.

For integration testing you can directly use `new ReportImpl()` instead of `new ReportWebServiceWrapper()`.